# Как с помощью виджета Positioned выровнять дочерний виджет по центру

Tags: flutter, dart

Как с помощью виджета **Positioned** выровнять дочерний виджет по центру, отняв высоту кнопок и паддинга сверху и снизу кнопок?
 Синий квадрат выровнян ВООБЩЕ по центру.

> MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - высота квадрата

```
Positioned(
 // (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 100.0) -> по центру вообще
 top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 100.0),
 left: _animation.value,
 //left: 0.0,
 child: Container(
  width: 100.0,
  height: 100.0,
  color: Colors.indigoAccent,
 ),
),
```

Красный квадрат выровнян ВООБЩЕ по центру с помощью виджета **Align**. Обратите внимание, он чуть ниже синего квадрата. Я его сделал чисто для сравнения.

> alignment: Alignment.center,

```
Align(
 alignment: Alignment.center,
 child: Container(
  width: 100.0,
  height: 100.0,
  color: Colors.pink,
 ),
),
```

Зеленый квадрат я пытаюсь выровнять НЕ ВООБЩЕ по центру, а поцентру белого фона, отняв контейнер с желтым фоном. Выровняв квадрат по центру, я прибавил к нему отступы(8.0+8.0) и высоту кнопок (36.0), ное все равно, точно не получается. Расстояние белого фона сверху зеленого квадрата, чуть больше расстояния белого фона снизу зеленого квадрата, я даже линейкой померял.

> top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 100.0) + 8.0 + 36.0 +
> 8.0,

```
Positioned(
 // (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 100.0) -> по центру вообще
 // 8.0 -> padding сверху кнопки
 // 36.0 -> высота кнопки
 // 8.0 -> padding снизу кнопки
 top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 100.0) + 8.0 + 36.0 + 8.0,
 right: 0.0,
 child: Container(
  width: 100.0,
  height: 100.0,
  color: Colors.green,
 ),
),
```

Может, я как-то в расчетах ошибся, выравнивая зеленый квадрат? Далее фото и полный код. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main.dart**

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
 with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

 AnimationController _controller;
 Tween _tween;
 Animation<double> _animation;

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _controller = AnimationController(
   vsync: this,
   duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
  )..addListener(() {
   setState(() {
    
   });
  });

  _tween = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: window.physicalSize.width / 2 - 100.0);

  _animation = _tween.animate(_controller);

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

  _controller.dispose();

 }

 void _funStart() {
  setState(() {
   _controller.forward();
  });
 }

 void _funStop() {
  setState(() {
   _controller.stop();
  });
 }

 void _funBack() {
  setState(() {
   _controller.reverse();
  });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
     child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      color: Colors.orangeAccent,
      child: Row(
       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
       children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
         flex: 1,
         child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () { _funStart(); },
          splashColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
          ),
          child: Text(
           'start'.toUpperCase(),
           style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
            fontSize: 16.0,
           ),
          ),
         ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 8.0,),
        Expanded(
         flex: 1,
         child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () { _funStop(); },
          splashColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
          ),
          child: Text(
           'stop'.toUpperCase(),
           style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
            fontSize: 16.0,
           ),
          ),
         ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 8.0,),
        Expanded(
         flex: 1,
         child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () { _funBack(); },
          splashColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
          ),
          child: Text(
           'back'.toUpperCase(),
           style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
            fontSize: 16.0,
           ),
          ),
         ),
        ),
       ],
      ),
     ),
    ),
    Positioned(
     // (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 100.0) -> по центру вообще
     top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 100.0),
     left: _animation.value,
     //left: 0.0,
     child: Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height: 100.0,
      color: Colors.indigoAccent,
     ),
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
     child: Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height: 100.0,
      color: Colors.pink,
     ),
    ),
    Positioned(
     // (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 100.0) -> по центру вообще
     // 8.0 -> padding сверху кнопки
     // 36.0 -> высота кнопки
     // 8.0 -> padding снизу кнопки
     top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 100.0) + 8.0 + 36.0 + 8.0,
     right: 0.0,
     child: Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height: 100.0,
      color: Colors.green,
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, расчёты у Вас неправильные и с синим, и с зеленым прямоугольником.
`MediaQuery.of(context).size` - это не про размер родительского виджета, здесь он не подойдёт.

Вам нужен `LayoutBuilder`, пример по коду из Вашего вопроса:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // MARK: - Для наглядных расчётов
    final containerHeight = 100.0;
    // MARK: - Вот здесь главный момент:
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              // MARK: - По центру родительского виджета - это:
              // 1/2 высоты родительского - 1/2 высоты виджета
              top: (constraints.maxHeight - containerHeight) / 2,
              left: 0.0,
              child: Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: containerHeight,
                color: Colors.indigoAccent,
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 50.0) +
                  8.0 +
                  36.0 +
                  8.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

// MARK: - Второстепенное для ответа
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Name App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Name Page'),
        ),
        body: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Никогда не используйте какие-то захардкоженые цифры, как в 3 варианте. Добавится какой-нибудь новый отступ и все рассыпется. К примеру, `Safe Area`.

---

UPD. Если центрировать именно по белой части, а не `Stack`, то вариант первый - добавить в вычисления высоту строки с кнопками. Вариант второй - разделить их в `Column`:

```
return Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      ... // MARK: - Контейнер с кнопками 
    ),
    // MARK: - Занимаем все оставшееся место, т.е. белый фон из примера 
    // и квадрат отцентрируется как надо без дополнительных расчётов.
    Expanded(
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                // MARK: - По центру родительского виджета - это:
                // 1/2 высоты родительского - 1/2 высоты виджета
                top: (constraints.maxHeight - containerHeight) / 2,
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уважаемый VAndrJ, огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: Уважаемый VAndrJ, но все равно не получается. Задача была отцентрировать по белому фону. Это значит, вся высота контейнера (желтый фон с кнопками и белый фон) - желтый фон с кнопками = белый фон. Белый фон делим на 2 (это половина белого фона) минус половина квадрата. Все равно не получается отцентрировать квадар. Вот пример после трез слешей /// top: (constraints.maxHeight - (8.0 + 36.0 + 8.0)) / 2 - containerHeight / 2,

Comment: @Anton , обновил ответ.

Comment: Уважаемый VAndrJ, еще раз огромное Вам спасибо!